# Getting numbers into a column in Python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of numbers that are tab-delimited with new line characters that looks something like this:

```
104     109     105     110     126     119      97     103\n
114     129     119     130     122     106     117     128\n
```

and so on. How can I use python to write all these numbers to a file in one column? i.e.

```
104\n
109\n
105\n
110\n
126\n
```

and so on. Fairly new to python so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you really want a leading space (or tab!) on each output line except the first? If not edit, your question. Also, your description of your input is "interesting" -- are there really tabs where you show spaces?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use `sed`. But if you must use Python, you need to replace all tab characters with newlines. Try something like this:

```
with open('input_file', 'rb') as infile:
    with open('output_file', 'wb') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.replace('\t', '\n'))
```

Comment: yeah, one liner in sed: `sed 's/\t/\n/g' input_file > output_file`

Comment: Agree, sed shines for this problem.

Comment: Spotted that and changed it about 5 minutes ago :).

Answer (score 1):

```
"\n".join("104 109 105 110 126 119 97 103\n 114 129 119 130 122 106 117 128\n".split())
```

Comment: Using `split` and `join` is unnecessary here and adds the overhead of a list creation. Comparing `split()` + `join()` to `replace()` with `timeit` shows that replace runs much faster (about 4x faster for the given data, with no file IO).

Answer (score 0):

Replace input_filename and output_filename with appropriate values.

```
f = open('input_filename','r')
nums = f.read().split()
f.close()
f = open('output_filename', 'w')
f.write('\n'.join(nums))
f.close()
```

[Edit] Reworked example that doesn't load the whole file into memory.  It is now very similar to Chinmay Kanchi's example.  But I use split where he uses replace.

```
with open('input_filename','r') as input:
    with open('output_filename', 'w') as output:
        for line in input:
            output.write('\n'.join(line.split()))
            output.write('\n')
```

Comment: But you'd be loading the entire file into memory, which is not wise when dealing with large datasets.

Comment: True.  I assumed it would be comparable the example the OP posted, which may be a bad assumption.  If the file isn't huge, however, it'll will work just fine.  ... I reworked it to be more efficient in all cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of tackling this problem. You could use `string.split` and `string.join`, but that seems inefficient, since you'd be converting a string into a tuple and back into a string.

Using regex, we replace one or more whitespace characters with a newline. The metacharacter `\s` represents any whitespace character), which in Python 2.7.1 is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` (and possibly additional whitespace characters, if UNICODE is set).

```
import re 

input_file = open('input_filename','r')
output_file = open('output_filename', 'w')
for line in input_file:
    output_file.write(re.sub('[\s]+','\n', line))
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: This is super-ultra-giga overkill for this task. It takes a whopping 17 times longer than just using `str.replace()`.

Comment: Wow, cool that you benchmarked this. Yes, you're right: I misread the original question and thought that the numbers had irregular separators. I'd delete my answer, but I think your comment is useful and informative. Thanks!

Comment: The `timeit` module makes microbenchmarks absolutely painless :).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is small, you can use `file.readlines()` to read all the lines into memory:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for row in [l.split() for l in fin.readlines()]:
        for col in row:
            print col
```

If the file is very large, read the lines into memory one at a time (I like to use a generator):

```
for row in open('input.txt'):
    for col in row.split():
        print col
```

In either case you can pipe the output to a new file:

```
python myscript.py >output.txt
```

Comment: You don't need to use a generator. A file acts as its own iterator. You can just use `for line in file:`.

Comment: Using readlines only to iterate over the resultant list is wasteful; iterate over the file. Use readlines ONLY if you actually need a list of lines AND you know that the file is small enough; otherwise if you don't know whether your file is large or small, code like it's large.